# Windows Server 2019 IIS development setup HTTPS errors

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to create a Windows Server 2019 IIS setup for development. I have my system automatically redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. I've copied a working development system from Windows Server 2016. IIS sets up fine until I try binding port 443. When I try starting the site, I get:

[image]

As you can see, I have no other sites running. I can confirm it by running:

```
appcmd list sites
```

and no others sites are running. I can get around this error by manually replacing the bindings for 443 from "All Unassigned" to my internal ip address 10.0.1.49. I've created a self-assigned certificate calling it "Local Host":

[image]

Now it says it can't securely connect to the page:

[image]

On my IE Browser Internet Options -> Advanced, the Use TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 are checked, and Use SSL 3.0 is unchecked.

I am running Fusion on a Mac Pro. My Windows Server 2016 virtual server does not have this problem, and I stopped IIS on it to make sure it was not the cause. This virtual Windows Server 2019 is a fresh install. I can't seem to find what is interfering or stopping it from running the generic default.aspx page (or any other valid aspx page). Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably forgot your Windows Server 2016 setup (a long time ago?). A self-signed certificate is not trusted by anyone, unless you ask Windows or the browser to trust it, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html#to-trust-self-signed-certificate

Comment: LOL. Yeah it was a long time ago. IE should give me "There's a problem with this website's security certificate" and an option to "Continue to this website (not recommended)" which will allow me to continue. I don't get that message.

Comment: Jexusmanager looks to be an interesting program. Unfortunately, even answering Yes to "Trust Self-Signed Certificate", the problem remains, i.e. IE can't connect securely to the page. Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you try to run SSL Diagnostics? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html It might show something more.

Comment: The diagnostic didn't show anything unusual or unexpected. The link to IIS Crypto only allows testing of site online. This weirdness seems to defy all logic.

Comment: I will then try another browser, like Chrome. IE11 has been obsolete (though still supported by Microsoft on paper), so you rarely need to care about what it says.

Comment: Interesting Chrome gives "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR". Firefox: "SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG". Same with TOR. Opera just says a generic "invalid response". They are telling me something, I just don't know what.